# Use same `navigationBarTitle` and `navigationBarItems` on two views which are shown based on condition

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I have a View which shows `Text` view to show help text for user to tap on plus icon to add group. Once group is added, it shows `List` view. To show navigation bar, I need to call `navigationBarTitle` and `navigationBarItems` on both `Text` and `List` view. Below is my code snippet.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Home:View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataStore:DataStore
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            if dataStore.groups.isEmpty {
                Text("Tap on + icon to add group.")
                    .font(.caption)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .navigationBarTitle(Text("My App Name"), displayMode: .automatic)
                    .navigationBarItems(
                        trailing:
                            NavigationLink(
                                destination:
                                    CreateGroup(),
                                label: {
                                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                                })
                    )
            } else {
                List(dataStore.groups) { groupElement in
                    GroupRow(group: groupElement)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("My App Name"), displayMode: .automatic)
                .navigationBarItems(
                    trailing:
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination:
                                CreateGroup(),
                            label: {
                                Image(systemName: "plus")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                            })
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to call `navigationBarTitle` and `navigationBarItems` only once rather than calling on both `Text` and `List` views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to call navigationBarTitle and navigationBarItems only
> once rather than calling on both Text and List views?

Yes, you can wrap condition into any container, like Group or xStack:

```
struct Home:View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataStore:DataStore
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Group {
                if dataStore.groups.isEmpty {
                    Text("Tap on + icon to add group.")
                        .font(.caption)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                } else {
                    List(dataStore.groups) { groupElement in
                        GroupRow(group: groupElement)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("My App Name"), displayMode: .automatic)
            .navigationBarItems(
                trailing:
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination:
                            CreateGroup(),
                        label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                        })
            )

        }
    }
}
```